# Get TypeScript to catch 'this' type mismatch errors?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a module with a function like so:

```
export module Network
{
    export function savePrefs( globals:Globals )
    {
       // [save globals.prefs to the database...]
    }
}
```

And originally I have the code that calls it is part of the Globals class, so it calls the above method using:

```
Network.savePrefs(this);
```

since, being an instance method inside the Globals class, the 'this' variable refers to a Globals instance. But later I decide to move that method to a module, and forget to change 'this':

```
export module Utils
{
    upgradePrefs(globals:Globals)
    {
        // [... upgrade stuff....] //
        Network.savePrefs(this); // OOPS!
    }
}
```

TypeScript does not generate an error for this.

I'd like to get TypeScript to give me an error when this happens, as 'this' does not match the required type (Globals) for the method being called. Is that possible with some kind of compiler configuration option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably missing the `noImplicitThis` compiler option, which causes references to `this` that are not in a context with a known `this` type (such as a class) to generate an error instead of having type `any`.  You might want to turn on `strict` (which includes `noImplicitThis` and a number of other useful options) and then turn off any options that are part of `strict` that you don't want.